# Regex to capture a repeated group of two words

Tags: regex

I am trying to form an expression that will capture a repeated group of two words. For example:

`Glass Magnifying Glass Magnifying.svg`

Should become:

`Glass Magnifying.svg`

I have an expression that works great that captures single word duplicates:

`\b(\w+)\s+\1\b`

But I don't have any idea how to modify this to capture double word duplicates.

I didn't include a language tag because I'm using the expressions in a program called Renamer.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

### Edit:

More examples below:

Before:

```
Glass Magnifying Glass Magnifying.svg
Question Mark Question Mark.svg
Quote Left Quote Left Alt.svg
Read More Read More.svg
Stroke Comment Stroke Comment Alt2 Alt.svg
Stroke Heart Stroke Heart.svg
```

After regex:

```
Glass Magnifying.svg
Question Mark.svg
Quote Left Alt.svg
Read More.svg
Stroke Comment Alt2 Alt.svg
Stroke Heart.svg
```

Comment: Thanks for adding your efforts, could you please do add more sample of inputs in your question to make it more clear, thank you.

Comment: Can an example be like `test test.jpg` also? OR `test bla bla.jpg` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following.

```
(\w+\s\w+)\s\1
```

Or, if the words have *hyphens*.

```
([\w-]+\s[\w-]+)\s\1
```

Comment: That worked beautifully also. I'm not sure what advantages the expression has over the previous post, but its syntax is a bit simpler.

Comment: @fmotion1, I was just implying an additional reference.  Glad it worked.

Comment: @fmotion1 - the difference is that this would match exactly two words repeating, whereas mine will match one or more words - basically any repeating expression.

Comment: The first expression works, but the second doesn't. I'm feeding it `This-Is This-Is.txt` and it's doing nothing. I changed the expression to the following: `([\w-]+[\s\-][\w-]+)\s\1` and it now seems to work.

Comment: @fmotion1, my mistake, I was implying, `word-A word-B word-A word-B`.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply include a space in your first match:

```
\b([\w ]+)\s+\1\b
```

https://regex101.com/r/OUEczL/1

Comment: Perfect! That worked great. I'll award you the answer in 7min. (There is a timer for awarding an answer).

Comment: Note this matches `"Fe Fi Fo Fum Fe Fi Fo Fum"`.

Comment: fmotion, I'm sure @But could do that by amending his/her answer, though you need to clarify what you mean by "that use-case".